# Can't create InnoDB table (error -1)

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm porting a rather simple table to my live db server and it's giving me this strange error when I try to create a InnoDB table, table create is:

```
CREATE TABLE `cobertura` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cep` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_cep` (`cep`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If i change the engine to MyISAM it works, if I change the table name to something else, it works.
If i create the table as MyISAM and do an engine alter to InnoDB I get error 121.
I tried looking on the folder where mysql stores the files to see if there's any trash there, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe show your ambient DB? Have you tried this in a new DB?

Comment: Found `SHOW ENGINES;` will reveal if an engine is supported though it is for me and I'm now trying to figure this out. Did you ever figure it out Rodrigo? Also `INSTALL PLUGIN innodb SONAME 'ha_innodb.so';` is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

While the database *may* have a dash (-) in the name it will prevent MariaDB (and therefore MySQL) from setting the engine to InnoDB...though this is at best a half-answer as while I am trying to import an entire database back in to the system there are *other tables* that get created *first without problems*. Unfortunately this issue is now forcing itself upon me and I do not have the time to start a whole new database name scheme policy. For now I'm changing the engine for *that particular database* to use MyISAM instead.

From *general* troubleshooting try:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

...and if InnoDB isn't installed apparently then try this:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN innodb SONAME 'ha_innodb.so';
```