# InnoDB - errno: 1005, sqlState: 'HY000' sqlMessage: "Can't create table (tableName) (errno: -1)",

Tags: sql, sequelize.js, innodb, myisam, sequelize-cli

I was trying to make club, and students database

I am using sequelize, my engine is innoDB
and I wrote like this

```
module.exports = (seq, DataTypes) => {
    const Club = seq.define("clubs", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        leader: {
            type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false
        },
        subleader: {
            type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
            allowNull: false
        }},
        
        {timestamps: false,
        tableName: "clubs"}
    );

    Club.associate = (models) => {
        Club.belongsTo(models.users, {
            foreignKey: "leader",
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "CASCADE"
        });

        Club.belongsTo(models.users, {
            foreignKey: "subleader",
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "CASCADE"
        });

        Club.belongsTo(models.clubtype, {
            foreignKey: "type",
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "SET DEFAULT",
            onUpdate: "CASCADE"
        })

        Club.belongsToMany(models.users, {
            through: models.user_club,
            foreignKey: "clubID"
        });
    };

    return Club;
};
```

However, this returned me an error
code: 'ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE',
errno: 1005,
sqlState: 'HY000',
sqlMessage: "Can't create table 'dbjshsus.clubs' (errno: -1)",

I was stuck in this error for hours, so I tried another way:
I opened my dbeaver, connected with my db,

and created a table names "clubs", and set my engine "innoDB"

However, this returned me an error "Can't create table 'dbjshsus.clubs' (errno: -1)"

I've searched about this error errno -1 but I couldn't find anything

I Also switched my engine to MyISAM, and then the table was created successfully...

I dont have any problems with foreign Keys,
and it even worked couple hours ago. In same code
dbjshsus.clubs was created successfully in innoDB, but not now

I changed my db names... and some of them works...
But the name also gets into same problem...
at some point, I can't use those names anymore...

I literally have no idea why is this error happening

Can Anyone give me the reason, and some solutions?

+
And Yes This is same problem with
[Can't create InnoDB table (error -1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602546/cant-create-innodb-table-error-1)

This didn't helped me that much..

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Can we see your full `create table` statement?

Comment: Are any of the tables your referring to MyISAM?

Comment: @Schwern
My Sql version is 5.5.43-log

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clubs`(
`id` TINYINT NOT NULL auto_increment ,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`leader` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`subleader` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`type` TINYINT NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`leader`) REFERENCES `users_test` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`subleader`) REFERENCES `users_test` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `clubtypes` (`id`) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB;```

Comment: Uh... yes actually some of them are myISAM, and the others are InnoDB

But It worked when I tried with InnoDB, but not now

Comment: 5.5 is a very old version of MySQL that gives very unhelpful error messages, [support ended in 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history). Try your setup on a newer version, such as 5.7 or 8 and you will get better error messages. You can use [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to try it out.

Comment: A simple search for "ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE', errno: 1005" comes up with "The foreign key “main id” must be of the same type as the primary key it refers."

Comment: @RickJames Or the foreign table is using a different engine, or file permissions... 5.5 issues the same error for a few different problems. 5.7 issues specific errors.

Comment: @Schwern I solved my problem by using just another db.. that is more up to date and using only InnoDB. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mineppl13 You're welcome, glad you got it fixed and upgraded.